# 英語が残っている: ヘルプセンター > バッジ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

バッジ名、およびバッジの説明に英語が残っています：ヘルプセンター > バッジ
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

```
Explainer: Edited and answered 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
Refiner: Edited and answered 50 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
Illuminator: Edited and answered 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0) 
自伝作家: Completed "About Me" section of user profile
識者: Read the entire tour page
```